# Read file as a list of tuples

Tags: python

I want to read a text file using Python. My list must be like this:

```
mylist = [(-34.968398, -6.487265), (-34.969448, -6.488250),
          (-34.967364, -6.492370), (-34.965735, -6.582322)]
```

My text file is:

```
-34.968398,-6.487265
-34.969448,-6.488250
-34.967364,-6.492370
-34.965735,-6.582322
```

My Python code:

```
f = open('t3.txt', 'r')
l = f.readlines()
print l
```

My results:

```
['-34.968398 -6.487265\n', '-34.969448 -6.488250\n', 
 '-34.967364 -6.492370\n', '-34.965735 -6.582322\n']
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One of the most efficient way to read delimited data like this is using [`numpy.genfromtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html). For example

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.genfromtxt(r't3.txt', delimiter=',')
array([[-34.968398,  -6.487265],
       [-34.969448,  -6.48825 ],
       [-34.967364,  -6.49237 ],
       [-34.965735,  -6.582322]])
```

Otherwise you could use a list comprehension to read line by line, split on `','`, convert the values to `float`, and finally produce a list of `tuple`

```
with open('t3.txt') as f:
    mylist = [tuple(map(float, i.split(','))) for i in f]
```

Note that when you open a file using `with` it will take care of closing itself afterwards so you don't have to.

Comment: Looks like: `mylist = [ast.literal_eval(line) for line in f]` is also viable

Comment: @JonClements that just feels like cheating :P

Comment: How to do the transpose of that? I mean, suppose a file with `N` lines containing `a,b,c`. Then, how to produce a list with 3 `N`-tuples, each tuple being the columns `a,b,c` resp.

Comment: @Sigur I've edited my post to instead suggest using `numpy.genfromtxt`. If you use that solution, you can say `a = np.genfromtxt()` then `a.T` is the transpose of that array.

Comment: I have a csv file containing tuples which I wish to import as a list of tuples. Currently the list comes up as a string. Have used ast.literal_eval but it causes memory issues and the program fails to execute.More details are at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60270005/import-csv-file-as-a-list-of-tuples

Answer (score 7):

Yes Cyber solution is best.

For beginners

1. Read file in Read mode.
2. Iterate lines by `readlines()` or `readline()`
3. Use `split(",")` method to split line by `'`
4. Use `float` to convert `string` value to `float`. OR We can use `eval()` also.
5. Use list `append()` method to append tuple to list.
6. Use try except to prevent code from break.

Code:

```
p = "/home/vivek/Desktop/test.txt"
result = []
with open(p, "rb") as fp:
    for i in fp.readlines():
        tmp = i.split(",")
        try:
            result.append((float(tmp[0]), float(tmp[1])))
            #result.append((eval(tmp[0]), eval(tmp[1])))
        except:pass

print result
```

Output:

```
$ python test.py 
[(-34.968398, -6.487265), (-34.969448, -6.48825), (-34.967364, -6.49237), (-34.965735, -6.582322)]
```

Note: A [readline()](https://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/inputoutput.html) reads a single line from the file.

Answer (score 1):

This code should do it:

```
ifile=open("data/t2mG_00", "r")
lines=ifile.readlines()
data=[tuple(line.strip().split()) for line in lines]
print(data[0])
```